Connection to sonarqube.abc.com on port 9443 failed: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "A connection attempt failed for a .NET project
I am trying to integrate SonarQube with Azure DevOps. But facing sonarqube service connectivity issue, Azure pipeline throwing the following error:
Connection to sonarqube.abc.com on port 9443 failed: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 194.132.xx.xx:9443"

I am able to access https://sonarqube.abc.com/9443 with IP: 194.132.xx.xx (hosted through nginx reverse proxy) inside the Remote Desktop(RDP) server but not outside it, even though the "ping sonarqube.abc.com" outside RDP gives the same IP address 194.132.xx.xx.
azure.yml
variables:
sonarqubeHost: "sonarqube.abc.com"
stages:
- stage: checkout  #Checkout the repository
displayName: Checkout
jobs:
  - job: checkoutJob
    displayName: Checkout Source Code
    steps:
      - checkout: self

- stage: PrepareAnalysis
dependsOn: Checkout
jobs:
- job: SonarQubePrepare
  displayName: 'Prepare SonarQube Analysis'
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Check DNS resolution for SonarQube server'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        $server = $env:sonarqubeHost
        try {
          $ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)
          Write-Output "DNS resolution succeeded: $server resolved to $($ip.IPAddressToString)"
        } catch {
          Write-Output "DNS resolution failed: $_"
          exit 1
        }
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Check connectivity to SonarQube server'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        $server = $env:sonarqubeHost
        $port = 9443
        try {
          $connection = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($server, $port)
          Write-Output "Connection to $server on port $port succeeded."
          $connection.Close()
        } catch {
          Write-Output "Connection to $server on port $port failed: $_"
          Write-Output "Attempting Test-NetConnection for more details..."
          Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $server -Port $port
          exit 1
        }

Task: 'Check DNS resolution for SonarQube server'
Output: DNS resolution succeeded: sonarqube.abc.com resolved to 194.132.xx.xx
Task: 'Check connectivity to SonarQube server'
Output: Connection to sonarqube.abc.com on port 9443 failed: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 194.132.xx.xx:9443"
Attempting Test-NetConnection for more details...
WARNING: TCP connect to (194.132.xx.xx : 9443) failed
WARNING: Ping to 194.132.xx.xx failed with status: TimedOut
What could be the possible issues ? How can I resolve this ?

This is a network problem: there is no connection from the CI/CD instance to your sonarqube server.
This could be anything network wise. But given the port number, it is unlikely if there are any organisational boundaries that there will be connectivity (eg. running on managed worker while sonarqube server is on premise).

@Richard I have created a SonarQube service connection under Azure Service Connection - Which is meant to connect the Azure CI/CD pipeline to the sonarqube server https://sonarqube.abc.com:9443, but still facing the issue.

Service connections identify and authenticate connections, they do not themselves provide any connectivity.

To integrate SonarQube with pipelines in Azure DevOps, it is recommended using the SonarQube extension which is published by SonarSource official. It provides the pipeline tasks to allow you can incorporate into your build definition(s) to enable additional SonarQube functionality in Azure DevOps environments.

Install install the SonarQube extension from Marketplace into your Azure DevOps organization/collection.


In the project where you want to run the pipeline, go to "Project Settings" > "Service connections" to create a SonarQube service connection. Provide the valid Server Url and Token of your SonarQube server on the service connection.


In the build pipeline:

Before the build task, add the SonarQubePrepare@6 task configure all the required settings prior to executing a build. You need to provide the SonarQube service connection on this task so that the task can generate credentials to let the pipeline agent can connect to your SonarQube server.

After the build and test tasks, you can add the SonarQubeAnalyze@6 task execute the source code analysis and upload the results to your SonarQube server. This task is not used in Maven or Gradle projects.

After the SonarQubeAnalyze@6 task, you also can optionally add a SonarQubePublish@6 task to publish the quality gate status to the summary page of the build to display letting you know if your code meets quality standards for production.




For more details, you can see the SonarQube documentation "Azure DevOps integration".

In addition, if you use Microsoft-hosted agents to run the build pipeline, ensure the server machine of your SonarQube is accessible via public networks. However, if you have firewall or proxy set on the server machine, you might need add the IP ranges/IP addresses of the possible Microsoft-hosted agents into the whitelist of your server machine (see "Networking").
If you use Self-hosted agents, I recommend you directly install the Self-hosted agents on the server machine, or the machines that can smoothly communicate with the server machine.


Have you tried as the steps shared in my answer above to integrate SonarQube with Azure pipelines? Is it helpful for you? @NanditaSingh
